# Memory row driver does not have enough driving power

Tags: driver, cmos, memory, non-volatile-memory

I am building the row driver of a piece of RRAM. Different from traditional memory, RRAM's cells are composed of resistor-like elements. I tried using a single inverter and a back-to-back inverter design (shown below), but they don't have enough driving power. The row line voltage is only about 25u Volts when connected with a grounded, 200-Ohms resistor. Ideally, the output voltage should be the same as the pumped voltage (VDDP). I am wondering how to achieve this?

Thank in advance for any advice!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem in VLSI design. You just need to add pairs of inverters in series, increasing the W/L ratios of the transistors by a factor of about 4X in each subsequent inverter as you get closer to the row line load. Each pair of inverters acts as a non-inverting buffer, but the drive strength increases by up to 16X.

The transistors in the inverter will start to get large, so you will probably need to use multiple parallel transistors (really just fingers of gate poly) to make the big inverters.